# Close JSP popup window from within backing bean?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jsf

Currently, I have a commandButton element in my jsp declared like this:

```
 <h:commandButton id="saveButton" value="Save" type="submit" action="#{backingbean.save}" onclick="window.close();" />
```

Once this button is clicked, the backing bean method will be called and the popup window will be closed. I don't want them to take place simultaneously. Upon button click, I'd rather call the save method first and close the window once the method returns.

I was wondering if I could close the popup inside the save method and leave the onclick event handler empty. Is it possible?

Is there a better way to close the window AFTER method save returns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the bean action method navigate to a page which contains just the following.

```
<script>window.close();</script>
```